# jinja variable cannot be fetched in cloud composer

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-composer

I tried to apply **DataprocInstantiateWorkflowTemplateOperator** using the tutorial provided by Google, but the value of the variable 'project_id' is not available in this operator with airflow version 2.4.3. Here is the [example provided by Google](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/tutorials/workflow-composer#airflow-2):

```py
"""Example Airflow DAG that kicks off a Cloud Dataproc Template that runs a
Spark Pi Job.

This DAG relies on an Airflow variable
https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts/variables.html
* project_id - Google Cloud Project ID to use for the Cloud Dataproc Template.
"""

import datetime

from airflow import models
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.operators.dataproc import (
    DataprocInstantiateWorkflowTemplateOperator,
)
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago

project_id = "{{var.value.project_id}}"


default_args = {
    # Tell airflow to start one day ago, so that it runs as soon as you upload it
    "start_date": days_ago(1),
    "project_id": project_id,
}

# Define a DAG (directed acyclic graph) of tasks.
# Any task you create within the context manager is automatically added to the
# DAG object.
with models.DAG(
    # The id you will see in the DAG airflow page
    "dataproc_workflow_dag",
    default_args=default_args,
    # The interval with which to schedule the DAG
    schedule_interval=datetime.timedelta(days=1),  # Override to match your needs
) as dag:

    start_template_job = DataprocInstantiateWorkflowTemplateOperator(
        # The task id of your job
        task_id="dataproc_workflow_dag",
        # The template id of your workflow
        template_id="sparkpi",
        project_id=project_id,
        # The region for the template
        region="us-central1",
    )
```

Then in airflow UI, I got this error:
[log airflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aswPb.png)

Someone knows what's the problem?

Someone knows why `project_id = "{{var.value.project_id}}"` doesn't work in this example?

Comment: I proposed you an answer, please check it and mark the answer as solved if it helps to solved your issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retrieve the current `project ID` in `Cloud Composer` globally, you can use a [prefined env variables](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/composer-2/set-environment-variables#reserved_variables) instead of using `Jinja` templating

Example for `project ID` in the `DAG` and `Python` code :

```py
project_id = os.getenv("GCP_PROJECT")
```

Then you can pass it in the operator.

Answer (score 0):

The answer Mazlum posted can work, or, if you look earlier in the tutorial you linked, there was a step to use the [Airflow UI](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/tutorials/workflow-composer#airflow-ui) to add an Airflow variable, which would resolve the Jinja templating error. I did take a closer look and saw that the `gcloud` command for that section is incorrect and I filed a bug flagging it.